# How to order by hot/rising posts

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have DB of posts with:

```
post_id(int(7)) user_id(int(7)) post_txt(text) post_time(varchar(30)) likes_count(int(10))
```

(the post_time is look like this "5-4-2016 17:41")

I want to order it by "hot posts" e.g. "likes_count/post_time".

How can I do it?

This is how I do it now:

```
$que_post=mysql_query("select * from user_post order by post_id desc");
```

PS. I know that this is not how you save likes usually, but I do it for purpose

Edit-Example data:

```
97||25||Hello world||8-4-2016 14:19||19
```

The algorithm I want to use is time/likes. I know its bad algorithm, but I just want to understand the basics.
I would like to know if you know good algorithm for that

Comment: Provide:  (1) Sample data; (2) Desired results; and (3) The rules you are using for "hot posts".

Comment: By "likes_count/post_time" do you literally mean the likes_count divided by the post time? If so, that seems like a bad algorithm because it will mean newer content will be less hot rather than more hot.

Comment: Do NOT use `mysql_*` it has been removed and it will not work anymore, use `PDO` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or `mysqli` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: @Tom what do you mean it has been removed?

Comment: Okay, so as long as you acknowledge that your query will actually do the opposite of what you want, the first thing to do is follow @Andrewus's suggestion and turn your `post_time` in to something you can actually do math on.

Comment: @Chris, you're right! I think, it'll be good idea to store in table both `DATETIME` and `INT` timestamp of a posttime. `DATETIME` is good for work with, `INT` is good for math.

Comment: I got the sql already build, but i will change it. Lets assume that its DATATIME, how can I now do it? (reposted from andrewus's answer)

Comment: @Andrewus It's not hard to convert between them, but maybe storing both would be simplest for the person who asked the question.

Comment: So should I save the date by DATETIME or by UNIX TIME?

Comment: PS. I use the function STRTOTIME to change it to time stamp

Comment: `DATETIME` is more comfortable to work with. In case of your question it's good to use `TIMESTAMP`, cause you want to sort by calculated value.

Answer (score 1):

You should change type of `post_time` field to `DATETIME` (read [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)).
All your lines have to be converted by some script to format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. When you do it, everything will work.

Your problem appears cause of sorting by alphabet as text. For example: 01.01.2016 as text is less than 31.01.1999.

Comment: I got the sql already build, but i will change it. Lets assume that its DATATIME, how can I now do it?

Comment: You can add field `new_post_time`, and do update with `STR_TO_DATE('8-4-2016 14:19','%m-%d-%Y %H:%i')` -- to convert your dates to correct format.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can convert the post_time column to use a date type, you want to find the number of seconds between it and now, e.g.

```
Order By like_count / (unix_timestamp(now()) - unix_timestamp(post_time)) Desc;
```

If changing the column type isn't an option, you can convert it on-the-fly using the str_to_date function, but that will potentially be quite a slow operation.